# How to use Vim in a part of Terminal with Go

Tags: go, vim, iterm2, tui

I'm trying to create TUI app with Go.
I'll make this app like dashboard.
And I want to use Vim as a part of Terminal(iTerm2) screen.

[image: 1]

And I want to use local vim env(NeoVim, Local vimrc and plugins).

How do I use local vim with go?
Or are there go libraries to use local vim?

My English isn't so good so feel free to ask me if there is anything unclear.
Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux).

Comment: I tried this  
1. `:vsplit` in vim  
2. `:terminal` on one screen  
3. Run go program.
In this case, I think go is running on vim.  
But I want to run vim on go.

Comment: If I use tmux, it will be I use tmux before running go app.
I want to start with running go app and running vim on this go app.

Comment: Kinda like how lazygit allows you to edit a file within its UI?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is inordinately difficult to do, and I would advise against it.

The only way to embed a terminal application like you're describing is to essentially implement a terminal emulator within your application and display its output within your application. There are libraries which can make this easier -- like [libvterm](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libvterm/), which vim uses to implement the `:terminal` command -- but even so, doing this will be difficult, particularly if you want to support advanced terminal functionality in the embedded editor (like mouse support).

A more common idiom for making an editor available in a terminal application is to launch the editor as a subprocess on demand, allowing it to "take over" the entire terminal while a file is being edited. Once the editor exits, your application can resume.

Comment: Thank you for your great advice!!
I won't support advanced functionality, so I'll try to use the libraries.

Comment: Don't expect it to be easy. This embedding is likely to remain the single largest source of complexity in your application, especially if you need to interface libvterm (which is a C library) to a Go application. Anything else you are doing will pale in comparison.